# Removing duplicates from an array. Errors on printing the hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, set

```
import java.util.*;
public class RemoveDuplicates {

private static Scanner ak;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ak = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k=0;
    System.out.println("enter the size of the array");
    int n=ak.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println("enter element "+(i+1));
        a[i]=ak.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.toString(a);
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> h=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if ((h.containsKey(a[i]))){
            k=h.get(a[i]);
            h.put(a[i],k+1);
        }
        else{
            h.put(a[i], 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.print(h);
    Set <Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> c=h.entrySet();

    System.out.print(c);
    System.out.println("these are the duplicates removed elements  ");

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> i=c.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        if (i.next().getValue()==1)
        System.out.println(i.next().getKey());

    }
  }
}
```

I have written a program to remove duplicates from an array using a HashMap but I am unable to print the correct output.
When I enter the input as size=4
and the array input as {1,1,2,3}
the iterator prints only "3" where as it should print "2,3"
**Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: you can use a `HashSet` if you want a fast solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if (i.next().getValue()==1)
System.out.println(i.next().getKey());
```

You're calling `next()` twice within one iteration - so you're checking the *count* for one entry, but then printing the *key* for the next entry. (And your indentation is horrible.) You want something like:

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = i.next();
    if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Or use an enhanced for loop to make it simpler:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : c) {
    if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon!I was frustrated for a long time for such a small thing. The eclipse editor is indenting all my code :-P so its their fault..:-D

Comment: @user2668314: I'd be shocked if the Eclipse editor *really* lined up the `System.out.println` along with the `if`... try reformatting that section of code. (And I'd personally suggest always using braces...)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you want is:

```
Integer[] arr = ....
INteger[] arr2 = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr)).toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

at this point `arr2` contains only unique elements of your source array in the same order. 
If you want to print array use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first - but that's not the case. The OP wants to completely delete all elements which occur more than once, not just de-dupe.

Comment: I didn't exactly get as to what you are doing. Could you explain your code in brief @AlexR.